# How to display iTunes search API / json results in the correct order

Tags: ios, json, itunes-search-api

Can anyone help me get the search results for iTunes apps to display in the correct order?

An examples is as follows:

http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=board%20portal&country=gb&entity=iPadSoftware

Invariably, this returns the results for an iPad app search in an order that looks neither like sort=popular or sort=relevant if the latter is even a correct parameter.

On an actual iPad the first app that appears for board%20portal or board+portal is Board Papers

Via iTunes on a Mac the first app that appear for board%20portal or board+portal is Bumpling Free

The JSON  displays Diligent Boardbooks as the first result which doesn't appear as the number one result for any parameters on an iPad.

Do I need to use a special parameter to get it into the right order. Are there any Enterprise Partner Feeds that I could use to get a more accurate order?

Thanks

Comment: You can to look at the request iTunes sends using Charles Proxy, there may be sort arguments to the query string. (Charles was just updated for Yosemite)

Comment: Yep tried that, the app store demonstrates good practice and correct certificates to stop me getting to the right info:)

Comment: Actually I had SSL proxying on, I'll try it without

Comment: I cold see the requests in Charles. On a request that is encrypted right-click on the url in the left pane and select PROXY. That will add that URL to the list of sites to proxy and show the https info in-the-clear. You will have to have added the Charles certificate. I tried this earlier and could see the requests and query parameters.